# Select and disable combobox

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to select and disable a combobox using the following jstl code but only the select is working not the disabled. how can I disable the combo?

```
   <select name="cat">
       <c:forEach var="attCat" items="${attCat}">
           <c:choose>
              <c:when test="${attCat.catId==fun.GetCatId(date, empList.empId)}">
                   <option value="${attCat.catId}" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" >${attCat.category}</option>
              </c:when>
              <c:otherwise>
                  <option value="${attCat.catId}">${attCat.category}</option>
              </c:otherwise>
           </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Comment: The `disabled="disabled"` must be on the `<select>`, not the `<option>`.

Comment: @Andreas I don't believe this to be the case.

Comment: The `<select>` is the combobox, and the `<option>` is a value in the drop-down list. You want to select an item (on `<option>`), and disable the combobox (i.e. the `<select>`). Note that disabling will prevent the value from being posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<c:when test="${attCat.catId==fun.GetCatId(date, empList.empId)}">
    <option value="${attCat.catId}" disabled="disabled" >${attCat.category}</option>
</c:when>
```

I have removed the `selected` attributes from the `<option>` tag as it doesn't make much sense to have a disabled *and* selected option.

Comment: I want to keep 'selected' to show users the preselected value and to disable same time to prevent changing.

Comment: I don't know if you can rely on doing this across all broswers.  You might want to rethink your design.

Comment: @HafsaAbdulgafoor Please review the answers given, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled="disabled"` must be on the `<select>`, not the `<option>`.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L292Lhw3/1/

**Update:** Remember that the selected value will not be posted when the combobox is disabled. To post the value, insert a `<input type="hidden">` with the preselected value.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to keep 'selected' to show users the preselected value and to
>   disable same time to prevent changing.

Problem is option with disabled attribute will allow user to change value:

```html
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option selected='' disabled=''>Selected</option>
</select>
```

You will need to use with `select` instead of `option` tag.

```html
<select disabled=''>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option selected=''>Selected</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `selected="true"` instead of `selected="selected"`

see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p9kqhw5L/) link